# Sending postmessage() to iframe instantly as the iframe loads in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe

I have a system where the outside project where the iframe is integrated is in angular, and the iframe code is also in angular. The iframe has certain query parameters like login id, password that get read instantly as the iframe loads, and works fine. A have to send another set of data that also need to be read instantly, what that i came across postmessage() and used it.

Outside project code:

```
      <iframe #challanFlowIframe
      src="http://url/query?username=&password="
      style="height: 600px; width: 1000px;"
      frameborder="50"
      (load)="validateAdminRole()"
      >
      </iframe>
```

```
  validateAdminRole(){
    const iframeWindow = this.challanFlowIframe.nativeElement.contentWindow;
    iframeWindow.postMessage('ADMIN', '*');
  }
```

the validateAdminRole() function is written inside the same component where the html template is present.

Iframe code:

In the main.ts of the iframe project i try to read the data, this is a standalone component project

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

import { UtilService } from './app/shared/util.service'

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));


  window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    if (event.data) {
      let utilService = new UtilService()
      utilService.saveRoleOfCaller(event.data)
    }
  })
```

What i find is that despite the code written in main.ts, the constructor and ngOnInit() runs before this function to read the message. Inside the ngOnInit() the code to read the query parameters is present, with the same i also want to read the role sent using postmessage()

in this way i make the standalone app

```
  ngDoBootstrap() {
    const element = createCustomElement(GenerateChallanDetailsComponent, {
      injector: this.injector,
    });
    customElements.define('app-generate-challan-details', element);
  }
```

Using: Angular 17

The problem is why does the postmessage() takes a while like 2-3 seconds to read the message. And is there a better way if not solution of this to get the role instantly.

Thanks for the help, i hope was able to explain the problem.

I read post from MDN and a couple of medium, tried to listen to the message from the component generatechallan (from the constructor, ngOnInit(), and event outside the class ie with plain javascript to find the time it takes to read the message) but didnt find any significant change. It sill takes around 2-3 second to read it.

Comment: PostMessage is an asynchronous function, so by definition not instant